# How to get applicationPath from HttpContext.Request in dotnet core 3.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I need to fetch data from HttpContext.Request in my custom middleware to provide public url for application assets.

How can you get `StoreName` & `FilePath` from this path:

`http://example.com/api/fileService/storage/{StoreName}/{path/to/file}`

This case needs new route template? I'm student, sorry for newbie question.

Comment: i'm unsure of what you are asking? do you have a string called StoreName and another with a filepath? do you need to create a url path after concatenating those into a new url string? string url = $"http://example.com/api/fileService/storage/{StoreName}/{path/to/file}". you can make extension methods that does this, and then use HtmlEncoder, etc. But i'm not sure what you're asking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HttpContext.Request.PathBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.pathbase) will return the current local path of your application.

As you know how your path is build, you can extract the parameters from there. When trying to match your "path/to/file" parameter remember that slashes will be url encoded as "path%2Fto%2Ffile".